# ASP.NET Web API possible deserialization issue while using flurl

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization, .net-4.6.1, flurl

I have a ASP.NET(C#, .NET 4.6.1) Web-Api-GET function which returns a complex object instance and is of generic type. Here is the return type definition (Note that the classes are much expansive in reality).

```
public class FileProcessInstance
{
    public FileProcessInstance()
    { }
    //ID that identifies file by primary key of log table
    public int FileLogID;

    //File name without path as received
    public string OriginialFileName;

    //Path with file name where file can be physically accessed
    public string FileSharePath;
}

public class CommonStatusPayload<T> : CommonStatus
{
    public CommonStatusPayload() : base(false)
    {
        Payload = default(T);
    }
    public CommonStatusPayload(T payload, bool status)
        : base(status)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    } 
    public virtual T Payload { get; private set; }
}

public class CommonStatus
{
    public CommonStatus() : this(false)
    {
    }
    public CommonStatus(bool status)
    {
        Status = status;       
    }  
    public bool Status { get; set; }   
}
```

Now my web api looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public CommonStatusPayload<List<FileProcessInstance>> GetFilesForProcessing()        
{
    List<FileProcessInstance> lst = new List<FileProcessInstance>() { new FileProcessInstance() { FileLogID = 1, FileSharePath = @"\\d\s", OriginialFileName = "d.txt" } };

    CommonStatusPayload<List<FileProcessInstance>> cs = new CommonStatusPayload<List<FileProcessInstance>>(lst, true);

    return cs;
}
```

The issue is, a call to this api from C# code would receive null as payload, while Postman request does receive proper payload.

Now my client code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lst = GetFilesForProcessing();
        }


        private static List<FileProcessInstance> GetFilesForProcessing()
        {
            List<FileProcessInstance> lst = new List<FileProcessInstance>();

            try
            {
                Task<CommonStatusPayload<List<FileProcessInstance>>> task = GetFilesForProcessingFromAPI();                
                task.Wait();

                 if (task.Result.Payload != null)
                    lst.AddRange(task.Result.Payload);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return lst;
        }

        private static async Task<CommonStatusPayload<List<FileProcessInstance>>> GetFilesForProcessingFromAPI()        
        {
            return await "http://localhost:10748/api/values/GetFilesForProcessing".ToString()         
                .GetAsync().ReceiveJson<CommonStatusPayload<List<FileProcessInstance>>>();
        }
```

I have observed that the return payload works if it were to be a a) list by itslef b) a local instance of `CommonStatusPayload<List<FileProcessInstance>>`. This makes me believe that there is a possible deserialization issue, when the result is handed  over to C# code from web-api. A fiddler check for the same request turns out to be just fine, just that C# client would not receive proper result.

Any guess as to what could be the underlying reason for payload being null?

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause of this issue. The private setter for Payload within CommonStatusPayload class is causing the deserialization to fail. Although for the intended behavior, i wanted the payload to be set only via constructor/method always to be associated with a relative status, at-least this change allows me to continue.

I did find some other questions here, related to JSON.NET with protected setters having same issues.